# Hadoop: Resource manager and Node manager are not starting

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Everytime I run start-yarn.cmd command the error occurs and resource manager and node manager does not starts
[Resource Manager Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYNLW.png)

[Node Manager window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj2tK.png)

[Yarnsite.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irou0.png)

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>ip_of_resource_manager</value>
</property>
```

I have added this to yarn-site.xml but did not worked.

Comment: What version are you running? ClassNotFound means you have an installation issue

Comment: hadoop version 3.3.0

Comment: Can you try newest version 3.3.4?